# Shiny - Where can I find ObserveEvent

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to shiny, and currently run the 0.10.1 version on OSX Yosemite (R version 3.0.3). Seems silly but I can't seem to find observeEvent nor eventReactive as valid functions! I assume it can be due to my version, however R does not allow me to upgrade to 0.14.1:

```
> install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/shiny_0.14.1.tgz", repos=NULL, method="libcurl")
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/shiny_0.14.1.tgz'
Warning in install.packages :
  'tar' returned non-zero exit code 1
Error in install.packages : file ‘https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/shiny_0.14.1.tgz’ is not an OS X binary package
```

On a side note: Is it possible to just use observe to replicate observeEvent?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you simply run `update.packages()`? Shiny 0.14 should still supports 3.0.3. Alternatively you can try install from source

Comment: I did. When I run update.packages() it stays with 0.10.1 and when I install from source I get the same error as above.

Comment: It was purely an issue with the R version. I used type="source" to update to the new versions and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there should be some other reason why you are not able to find those function.

Anyway you can use isolate() inside observe to stop a reactive dependency. the sum of input$first and input$second will be printed on the **console** only when input$first changes.

This is the code:

```
    library(shiny)


    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(


       titlePanel("Observe with Isolate"),


       sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
             sliderInput("first",
                         "Number of bins:",
                         min = 1,
                         max = 50,
                         value = 30),
             sliderInput("second",
                         "Number of bins:",
                         min = 1,
                         max = 50,
                         value = 30)
          ),


          mainPanel(

          )
       )
    ))


    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

       observe(
               print(input$first + isolate(input$second))
       )
    })


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```